# Issue in passing URL special char(s) - ClickCounter php script

Tags: php, mysql

**OBJECTIVE of script**: To take a URL and AdID that is being passed and count it in the database and then pass the user to the passed url

**How it works** : Once link is passed to script it takes AdID and logs the click in the database row +1 and then redirects them to the link.
Database Layout :

- Table : ads
- Row : clicks

example of passed link : 
http://yourdomain.com/clickcounter.php?AdID=43&RedirectURL=http://stackoverflow.com

**ISSUE** : It is not passing any url that has special char(s) in it. like the ? or the &

- Obvious issue  : still using mysql_query. I haven't learnt the new mysqli way completely yet

Example of trouble link :
https://www.demoexample.com/index.aspx?d=111&prog_id=tttt

**BENIFIT to others** : Others can use this script to do what I'm doing. Count how many times a link/ad/any url has been clicked to measure usage/clicks on  a link/ad.

```
<?php
require('config.php');

    // Update Ad Pull/Display count
    $AdID= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['AdID']);
    $UpdateADHitDisplay = mysql_query("UPDATE ads SET clicks = clicks +1 WHERE ID = '$AdID'");

    // Get Redirection Inforamtion
    $RedirectURL = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['RedirectURL']);
    header("Location: $RedirectURL");

?>
```

I don't I understand how to do this complete with urlencode here is what I tried.

```
// Get Redirection Inforamtion
$RedirectURL = $_GET['RedirectURL'];
//$FixedURL = urlencode($RedirectURL); // didn't work
    function url_encode($RedirectURL){ // then i tried to create a function. it pases the first part of the url, but nothing past the first ? or special char
 return urlencode(utf8_encode($RedirectURL));
```

}
    header("Location: $RedirectURL");

Comment: Seems this mysql_real_escape_string call is pointless and causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The value of parameter RedirectURL in your link must be [urlencoded](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) and there is no need in `mysql_real_escape_string()` for `$RedirectURL` variable